# IndexOutOfBounds while using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, prepared-statement

Does anyone have an idea why I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds -1 when I try to put multiple PreparedStatements into a single database transaction? It happens right when I try to set the first item in the prepared statement. This goes against everything I've been reading and can't seem to figure it out.

```
  PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Connection conn = null;


        // Fetch the query and the request out of the QueryRequest object
        conn = cpds.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        for (PrepStatementHolder a : query)
        {
            try
            {
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(sampleTimestamp, data) values(?,?)");
                stmt.setLong(0, a.getTimestamp());
                stmt.setBytes(1, a.getBinaryData());
                stmt.executeQuery();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
                errorLog.error("Query: " + a.getQuery() + " Timestamp " + a.getTimestamp() + " Data " + a.getBinaryData());
                return false;

            }
        }

        conn.commit();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

        return true;
```

Requested stack:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: ja
va.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:74)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.handleThrowable(NewPoole
dConnection.java:505)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setLong(NewProxyPr
eparedStatement.java:184)
        at com.joy.database.DBRunnable.dbCallInsert(DBRunnable.java:293)
        at com.joy.database.DBRunnable.run(DBRunnable.java:129)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$201(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.batch(CorePreparedStatement.jav
a:121)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.setLong(JDBC3PreparedStatemen
t.java:331)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setLong(NewProxyPr
eparedStatement.java:170)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please post your full stacktrace so we can see what is going on exactly.

Comment: The placeholders indexes start at `1` .

Comment: Thanks @Berger :)

Comment: Although @Berger is right, this should not throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It should throw an `SQLException`. If you are using a recent version of your driver, please consider filing a bug.

Comment: Just in case, could you add the stacktrace ?

Comment: Sure as soon as I get back to the office I will add.

Comment: Stack trace added as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of prepared statements start at 1 not a 0

```
stmt.setLong(0, a.getTimestamp());
stmt.setBytes(1, a.getBinaryData());
```

it should be

```
stmt.setLong(1, a.getTimestamp());
stmt.setBytes(2, a.getBinaryData());
```

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setLong(int,%20long)):

> ```
> /**
>  * Sets the designated parameter to the given Java <code>long</code> value.
>  * The driver converts this
>  * to an SQL <code>BIGINT</code> value when it sends it to the database.
>  *
>  * @param parameterIndex the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, ...
>  * @param x the parameter value
>  * @exception SQLException if parameterIndex does not correspond to a parameter
>  * marker in the SQL statement; if a database access error occurs or
>  * this method is called on a closed <code>PreparedStatement</code>
>  */
> void setLong(int parameterIndex, long x) throws SQLException;
> ```

the first parameter is **1**